# Ionic in-app purchase with multiple accounts in app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase

I've a question about in-app purchase subscription. In my app you can create multiple account. 
this is an example of my problem.

```
Login paolo.rossi@gmail.com and buy premium,
Logout paolo.rossi@gmail.com
Login paolo.verdi@gmail.com
I've already premium and I can't buy
```

How to solve this?
In many app you can buy premium in the same phone with different account. is it a ionic limitation?

Comment: which plugin are you using?

Comment: Hi, I use Ionic native in app purchase plugin

Answer (score 1):

I cannot answer how to achieve this in Iconic but this is the general approach I used in Android.

So the idea is to use your own back-end server to do two things:

> 1: Verify the payment details from your server with the Google. (This prevents hacking apps like Freedom)
>
> 2: Use your server to deliver the content and verify expiry.

The approach would be:

1. Login paolo.rossi@gmail.com and buy premium (Send payment data to **your server** and verify with the **Google/Apple** that the payment is valid and not a fraud. After successful verification, the server sends subscription data like **userId** and e**xpiry time** to the app. The app should store this data in the **local storage**)
2. Logout paolo.rossi@gmail.com.(Remove subscription details from the **local storage**)
3. Login paolo.verdi@gmail.com. (On login **send a request** to your server "**Does this person has a premium subscription?**" since Verdi does not have the subscription the server should send a **negative response**.)
4. The app shows you don't have the premium subscription. And Verdi can buy it.

So basically we bound the userId with the subscription and used our own server to verify the subscription.

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Hey Kishan, but if the plugin or the store use the same Google account? when you try to make the payment it would tell you you have an older subscription.... How the app knows if the user remove their subscription? could we follow this on a chat?

Comment: @JuanFernandezSosa I get your point. This is a limitation. The user has to login to the DEVICE with some other Google Account. Even If the user cancels the subscription, Google does not allow to buy a new subscription until the current subscription is expired.

Comment: @JuanFernandezSosa We have a daily CRON job on the server which gets expiry time of the purchases using Google API that are currently expired.